iOS: Pop Up Button menu layout
I am trying to add an option to a ViewController for an iOS app that allows the user to select one of 6-8 constant options. Other platforms have radio buttons or easy drop-down menus that provide this functionality, but apparently iOS does not.
Anyway, I'm currently trying to implement this as a "Pop Up Button" in a storyboard. Here is what it looks like in storyboard, which is basically what I want:

But here is what it looks like in Simulator:

Can anyone suggest a way to fix the layout so the menu items appear in a single column? Related: if you could point me towards a decent tutorial of how to implement a "Pop Up Menu" in storyboard that would be very much appreciated.

Tim can you provide some code what you tried?.

You're right that a radio button is not a standard SwiftUI component, but it's easy to create one. See SwiftUI: How to implement Radio button in SwiftUI

@OmSanatan there's no code involved in what I posted so far, except to bind each menu item to an empty action handler

Here's a partial answer: adding this code to say, a viewDidLoad override fixes the layout, at least for iOS 16+ which is what I was testing against. I guess I should test under earlier iOS systems to see what happens there.
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    myButton.menu?.preferredElementSize = .large
}


UPDATE
I have now run 6 tests on 3 simulated operating systems with and without the following code in the hosting UIViewController:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        myButton.menu?.preferredElementSize = .large
    }
}

And here's how the menu displays under those conditions



Code Fix
iOS 15.5
iOS 16.4
iOS 17.4




yes
.large
.large
.large


no
.large
.small
.large



So it appears the "default" preferredElementSize changed between iOS 16.x and iOS 17, and if I hadn't happened to be testing against an older iOS I wouldn't have known.
Further, if I implement the menu in code instead of in storyboard then I always get the .large layout, so this seems to have something to do with how the storyboard instantiates this object under different operating systems.
It's curious that at least under XCode 15.3, interface builder doesn't include an option to set the preferred element size like it does for other properties that are critical to make this work.
